# Jenkins - pipeline script from SCM to execute on the slave and not master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

So I am trying to use Pipeline script from SCM but I dont want to clone the repo I specify there and then the repo I specify in the Jenkinsfile.

Also, I see that the “Pipeline script from SCM” checks out the repo to master or might be to another slave. I want to checkout the code ones to the slave with Label X and then after passing the jenkinsfile I dont want to clone again from the file.

EG:
Lets say I have repo A which has jenkinsfile. I want my pipeline job to clone repo A to fetch the jenkinsfile into a slave with label X so that I dont have to clone the same repo again as part of the jenkinsfile execution.

Is this possible?